# Select into taking lot of time in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the following query in SQL Server but it's taking around 1 hour to run. Table 'dbo.AccessControl' has approx 3 million records and 'dbo.username' table has 3.5k records. Is there any way to optimize this query because I don't think a single left join should take this much of time for just 3 million records.

```
select isd.*,ac.username1+','+ac.Username2+','+ac.Username3 as UserName 
into dbo.username
from dbo.details isd
left outer join dbo.AccessControl ac
on isd.LocationId=ac.LocationId
and isd.DepartmentId=ac.DepartmentId
and isd.productId=ac.productId;
```

Comment: Try an inner join unioned with (one or more (i.e. three)) anti-joins.  I've seen many instances where an inner join completes immediately, and a left join takes ~forever.

Comment: Please post the execution plan. Do you have indexes ont the join columns? Are they used? How many are the estimated rows in the plan? Your query could result in 3M * 3.5 rows after all. *Why* are you trying to create a new table with all that data?

Comment: Have you checked Activity Monitor while the query executes? This will show if there are any locking or IO issues, even display the query's execution plan

Comment: Please post the execution plan. This is the only thing that will show eg, if the indexes are used or tempdb is used because there aren't enough indexes

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to optimize this query because I don't think a single left join should take this much of time for just 3 million records.

In your case,i think there might be some kind of locking,blocking which is causing this query to run this long or you might have to ran into some kind of bottleneck..

To find out,why your query is running this much time...run below query in a separate window(You can also use Activity monitor to display the same)

```
select   status,command,blocking_session_id,wait_type,last_Wait_type
from sys.dm_exec_requests where session_id=<<select into sessionid>>
```

This should give you a clue on whats happening ..

If you are in a version > SQL2014,you can know live status of the query by following below steps

```
    Set statistics profile on
   your query
```

and then run below query in a sepereate window

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_query_profiles
 where session_id=your session id
```

Comment: SSMS's Activity Monitor can display this information for all SQL Server versions. It could be locking, IO or tempdb spillover due to lack of indexes